# Android App no longer visible by Android 1.5 on devices

Tags: android, android-manifest

My last update on the Android Market caused my application to be no longer available to Android 1.5 devices.

I have changed the following:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

To this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>

<!-- Support all screen types and allow resizing of the layout -->
<supports-screens 
        android:anyDensity="true" 
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="false"/>
```

I'm not sure what went wrong... Any tips will be greatly apreciated!

Thanks for the help!

-Jona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it is due to the attribute "android:targetSDKVersion" was first introduced in API level 4 and therefore it will be unavailable for API level 3 devices

Comment: So you think removing it will do the trick? Anyone can confirm this?

Comment: I have to admit I do not know the answer to that.. perhaps someone else can answer?  But if I should guess I would say yes

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I actually think you might be correct.  I'll set your answer as the correct one... If anyone else confirms this would be great.